# I have cancer and I don’t want to tell my family

Tags: halal-haram, family, lying

I recently got diagnosed with ovarian cancer. My family knows that I got a tumour removed, but I told them that the tumour is non cancerous, which is not true. I simply don’t want to hurt them, therefore this is only between me and my parents. They’ve asked us many times about the tumour and we swore that nothing was wrong. I normally don’t lie about anything, but this just can’t be said.

Is it permissible for me to lie about my condition and say that nothing’s wrong?

Comment: Lying is not permitted. If there truly is a need then what one can do is use tawriyah, a saying where the speaker intends to mean one thing while the listener interprets it as something else, see e.g. [here](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/27261/).